# Lie algebra normalizer centralizer

Tags: lie-algebras

Def. Lie algebra 
A lie algebra is a vector space L over a field F together with a multiplication
L × L → L
(x, y) → [x, y]   [x, y] = xy - yx
satisfying the following axioms
1) [x, x]=0
2) [[xy], z] + [[yz], x] + [[zx], y] = 0

Def. Sub algebra, Ideal
let L is lie-algebra over field F and let H, K are subspace of L.
We then set [H, K] := span({[h, k] ∈ L ｜ h ∈ H, k ∈ K }
that we have to ensure that this is a subspace of L.
Lie sub algebra of L is a subspace H with [H, H] ⊂ H.
Lie ideal of L is subspace K with [K, L] ⊂ K.

K⊂L, K is sub algebra
The normalizer of a sub algebra K of L is defined by Nl(K) = {x∈L | [x, k]∈K  for all k∈K}.
The centralizer of subset K of L is Cl(K) = {x∈L | [x, k] = 0  for all k∈K}.

Q : Prove that if K is sub algebra of L, then Cl(K) is ideal of Nl(K).

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Please do **not** deface the question after it's solved.

Answer (score 2):

You need to show that if $a\in C(K)$ and $b\in N(K)$ then $[a,b]\in C(K)$,
that is $[[a,b],c]=0$ for all $c\in K$. By the Jacobi identity,
$$[[a,b],c]=[a,[b,c]]+[b,[c,a]].$$
Now, $[b,c]\in K$ and so $[a,[b,c]]=0$ and $[c,a]=0$.